# Em Python, pesquisar uma string a partir da informação de uma coluna?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Estou no Jupyter Notebook trabalhando com Python.

Tem um dataframe com os campos nome e texto, no texto, que é um txt carregado, quero pesquisar se existe a string que é exatamente o valor no campo nome.

Dataframe:

[image: Imagem do dataframe]

Desejo ter como resultado todas as linhas do dataframe com resultado se o valor do campo nome foi encontrado no texto ou não.

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi corretamente, você precisa **de todas as linhas que tenham o conteúdo da coluna `nome` na coluna `texto`**.

Você pode tentar algo como a linha de código abaixo, com o método `isin`, se for comparar apenas o que **contenha o valor, mas que não precisa ser exatamente igual**:

```
df.loc[df.nome.isin(df['texto'])]
```

Caso queira os valores iguais, você pode comparar diretamente os valores de cada registro nas colunas. A linha de código abaixo retorna os registros com `True` ou `False` para cada um comparado:

```
df['nome'] == df['texto']
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Obrigado Ruan, isso mesmo vc entendeu bem, só que não obtive resultados com esses códigos, eu consegui um resultado com o código abaixo:
```
data[['nome' in x for x in data['texto']]]
```


O seu segundo código veio tudo falso, acho que deve estar comparando conteúdo dos campos, mas o campo nome sempre é bem enxuto, o texto são páginas de texto e tenho que encontrar neste exatamente o conteúdo do campo nome.

Mas ainda estou analisando e ver se consigo algo melhor.
Grato

Answer (score 1):

***CONTAINS***

Você poderia usar o metodo CONTAINS que é semelhante ao LIKE do SQL.

```
df = df[df['nome'].str.contains('INVESTIMENTOS', na = False)]
```

Nesse caso a saída seria que o DF agora teria apenas itens relacionados a INVESTIMENTOS na coluna NOME.

***MATCH***

Já o Match é quando retorna uma palavra precisa, exemplo:

```
df = df[df['nome'].str.match('GIRASSOL FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM ACOES', na = False)]
```

Iria te retornar apenas o DF que iria ter apenas "GIRASSOL FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM ACOES" na coluna NOME e todas suas afiliações na coluna TEXTO.

Comment: Entendi, mas ao invés de colocar a palavra precisa, eu quero que ali contenha o conteúdo da coluna valor, e que este possa ser encontrado na coluna texto.

Comment: Parciliano, poderia me citar um exemplo para que eu possa ver em uma visão mais estruturada?

Comment: Oi @Fr0St, meu dataframe atual está com o seguinte formato - data.columns['nome', 'nome_arquivo', 'texto'].
Todoas as colunas são strings, desejo, pegar a coluna 'nome' e verificar se todo o conteúdo dela encontro exatamente em alguma parte na string da coluna 'texto' e, se possível, ter como resultado todos os resultados se encontrou ou não. Posteriormente desejo ter este resultado exportado para csv. Grato.